# Write to an excel file from multiple threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, excel, selenium, selenium-grid

I have a selenium test that reads and writes to an excel file. The reading is achieved by a dataProvider that loads all data into a hashmap. I now use Grid to run multiple threads at the same time. How do I achieve the writing with multithreading? I read about synchronize method but when I apply it to the outputStream file I get failures.

My code:

```
public static void createOutputFile(String inputFilePath) {

    inputFilePath = "InputPath";
    outputFilePath = "OutputPath";

    try {
        inputFile = new FileInputStream(new File(inputFilePath));
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputFile);
        inputFile.close();
        // save input data as output
        outputFile = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
        workbook.write(outputFile);
        outputFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static synchronized void writeToFile(Integer rowNumber, Integer cellNumber, String text) {
    try {
        //recreate workbook
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(outputFilePath));
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(cellNumber);
        if(cell == null) 
            cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).createCell(cellNumber, Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
        file.close();  
        outputFile = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
        if (rowNumber != null && cellNumber != null) {
            try {
                cell.setCellValue(text);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Updating the file failed " + outputFilePath); 
            }   
        }
        workbook.write(outputFile);
        outputFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by failures?

Comment: You've read about synchronized methods, but why have you not tried them?

Comment: make ur method writeToFile to be synchronized and see if you still get the error

Comment: @Adam Just wondering: do you think the best way to learn about multi-threading is to but so much complicated context around? Why not focus on "how do I program in Java using multiple threads" first?

Comment: @npinti: I get this error: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@c0fc09e0
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:500)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1417)
 at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:179)
 at

Comment: @nafas  I've actually tried it as I mentioned in my question, I tried to synchronize the method itself but only the last thread is updating, I tried to synchronize on fileoutputstream but I get error message

Comment: @Laurentiu L, please read my question, I mentioned that I tried it

Comment: @Adam you said it, but didn't show it in your sample code.

Comment: @Jägermeister sorry I found you're comment very rude. I said that I use multithreading using selenium grid.

Comment: I didnt want to be rude: what I am telling you: you should not choose to "learn" about threads using a complex setup. Or in other words: why do you want to use "grid" to run multiple threads; when you knowledge on "running stuff with multiple threads" is somehow limited? All I am saying is: reduce your problem to the bare mimimum. And the bare minimum is not running grid with multiple threads, but probably a single class that has several threads writing to the same file.

Comment: @Adam I think you are not appending to the file in your writeToFile method, you rather create a new stream everytime, you should use a writer that can append

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show that you are synchronizing the method, can you paste your synchronized code?

Just in case remember - Synchronized static methods are synchronized on the class object of the class the synchronized static method belongs to, which is different from instance synchronized methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, most likely lies here: `outputFile = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);`. What this does, is that it creates a new stream which points to the beginning of the file. Thus, sequential calls will overwrite previous material. To fix this, simply use another version of the constructor: `outputFile = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath, true);` which will append the bytes from the stream at the end. Do not forget to make your method as synchronized:

```
public static synchronized void writeToFile(Integer rowNumber, Integer cellNumber, String text) {
    try {
        //recreate workbook
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(outputFilePath));
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).getCell(cellNumber);
        if(cell == null) 
            cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber).createCell(cellNumber, Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
        file.close();  
        outputFile = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath, true);
        if (rowNumber != null && cellNumber != null) {
            try {
                cell.setCellValue(text);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Updating the file failed " + outputFilePath); 
            }   
        }
        workbook.write(outputFile);
        outputFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: mate, don't u mean new FileInputStream(new File(outputFilePath),true); instead?

Comment: @nafas: Froom what I am understanding, the `outputFile` stream is being used for writing. Also, the `FileInputStream` does not seem to have a constructor similar to what you are specifying.

Comment: you are right mate, still don't think the code would work, my opinion is that it requires a complete redesign (not your code but the whole program) to make it for multithreading application

Comment: @nafas: I understand you point. The method looks pretty self contained, thus adding the `synchronized` keyword should help, but with the level of provided information, I'd say that my answer is purely speculative.